# Не работает анимация c ListBox WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

У меня есть  две ThicknessAnimation для грида. Когда внутри грида находится только например button, все рабоатет как надо. Но если я помещу внутрь listbox, то срабатывает уже только вторая анимация (SecondAnimation). Не могу понять, почему так происходит.
Вторая анимация вызывается по нажатии на кпоку.

> View

```
 <Grid  Style="{StaticResource NewsDescriptionGrid}" Grid.RowSpan="3" Height="442"  VerticalAlignment="Bottom"  >
        <Button x:Name="ChangeGrid"/>
        <ListBox  Background="Transparent" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"  BorderThickness="0" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedArticle}" ItemsSource="{Binding ArticlesDescription_list}" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="437" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="798"   Grid.RowSpan="2" Margin="-1,0.2,-0.4,0"  >
            <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                                <ContentPresenter />
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>

            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
        <Grid   Grid.RowSpan="2">

            <Image Source="{Binding UrlFirst}"  RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Canvas.Left="334" Canvas.Top="15" Margin="386,22,4.2,95">
            </Image>
            
        </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
```

> Dictionary

```
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Grid}" x:Key="NewsDescriptionGrid">
    <Style.Setters>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="525,0,-522.4,2.4"></Setter>
    </Style.Setters>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Grid.Loaded">
            <EventTrigger.Actions>
              
                <BeginStoryboard Name="animation">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ThicknessAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin"  From ="525,0,-522.4,2.4" To="-1,7.2,3.6,-3.6" Duration="0:0:2"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger.Actions>
        </EventTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=ChangeGrid, Path=IsPressed}" Value="true">
            <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                <RemoveStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="animation" />
                <BeginStoryboard Name="secondanimation" >
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ThicknessAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin"  From ="-1,7.2,3.6,-3.6" To="10,-664,-7.4,572.8" Duration="0:0:2"/>

                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
        </DataTrigger>
        
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: `У меня есть две ThicknessAnimation для грида.` - я вижу 3... Что такое `ChangeSecondGrid` и `ChangeGrid`? Почему вы делаете такие дикие значения (`10,-664,-7.4,572.8`)? Если у вас такие значения, то это сразу говорит о том, что вы неверно разрабатываете дизайн. И да, мне совершенно не нравиться, что вы используете 2 аккаунта!! Этому не место на SO!

Comment: @EvgeniyZ исправлено. ChangeGrid это название у кнопки. Мне действительно нужны именно такие значения Margin

Comment: Пожалуйста, не забывайте, что SO это не форум, а сайт, где сообщество совместными усилиями собирает полезную информацию не только для авторов, но и для будущих читателей. То есть, ваши вопросы должны быть полезны и быть как можно более информативны. Сейчас вот вопрос "не работает анимация", ну вот берем, копируем это все, запускаем и что видим? Кнопка то хоть нажимается? Нет, а почему? А потому, что поверх нее `ListBox`, который берет все клики на себя, а как это связано с анимацией? А не как. И как быть? Наверно сделать прозрачный фон и установить `IsHitTestVisible`, а лучше переписать стиль.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Спасибо за помощь!